# Ubuntu/Postfix not receiving emails from outside

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp, email-server

I am trying to configure my Amazon EC2 instance to receive emails with postfix. I tried for hours but I never received an email. If I send email from same server terminal it works. This is working

```
echo "My message" | mail -s subject noreply@example.com
```

But if I try to send email from outside like gmail. I don't receive it. My port 25 is open. I am not receiving any delivery failed messages too. Couldn't find anything related issue from postfix log too. Appriciate if someone can help me to figure out the issue.

Here is my postfix config file.

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = example.com
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
```

[image]

As Alex suggested the swaks output as bellow.

```
=== Trying 52.62.94.158:25...
=== Connected to 52.62.94.158.
<-  220 example.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
 -> EHLO ip-172-31-21-89.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
<-  250-example.com
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-SIZE 10240000
<-  250-VRFY
<-  250-ETRN
<-  250-STARTTLS
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250 DSN
 -> MAIL FROM:<test@gmail.com>
<-  250 2.1.0 Ok
 -> RCPT TO:<noreply@example.com>
<-  250 2.1.5 Ok
 -> DATA
<-  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
 -> Date: Sat, 12 Mar 2016 23:08:43 +1100
 -> To: noreply@example.com
 -> From: test@gmail.com
 -> Subject: Test
 -> X-Mailer: swaks v20130209.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 -> 
 -> This is a test mailing
 -> 
 -> .
<-  250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E44EE642AD
 -> QUIT
<-  221 2.0.0 Bye
```

And I have received that email. Then again I tried sending an email form my Gmail. Unfortunately it failed. And when I try to check my noreply@example.com email from here. It says "Bad" http://verify-email.org/

Comment: Install swaks 'yum install swaks/apt-get install swaks' and then execute 'echo "Hello world" | swaks -s ec2.instance.ip --to user@your.domain.com --from test@gmail.com --h-Subject "Test" --body -' from any other linux box. Not from the server itself. Add the output to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MX record points to the name `smtp.example.com`, but this name doesn't have any address records.

```
$ host example.com
example.com has address 52.62.94.158
example.com mail is handled by 10 smtp.example.com.

$ host smtp.example.com
Host smtp.example.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Mail for your domain is therefore undeliverable.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I have updated MX records. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a second solution, which is completely and oversight, similar to yours with the MX. I was able to send emails out of the server, as well as to other virtual domains on the same server. But I was not able to receive anything from outside the server, but was able to receive from other virtual domains.

I simply forgot to enable the firewall.

```
sudo ufw allow Postfix
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw status
```

Hopefully it will help someone sometime in the future.

Comment: What does enabling the firewall do?

Comment: @WorksforaLiving the firewall night have been turned off. I just repeat the command to make sure i got everything running smoothly.