# Not able to receive emails on Postfix

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

I installed a mail server with Postfix and Dovecot on Debian. I can send emails without worries to Outlook, Yahoo, ...BUT I can't receive emails from outside.

I use my internet box (free) as a router. I redirected flows comes on 993, 143, 25 and 587.

I use NOIP as DNS. I added the records needed for the MX part.

```
yacine@mezianeyacine:~$ nslookup -type=mx mezianeyacine.sytes.net
Server:         192.168.1.254
Address:        192.168.1.254#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mezianeyacine.sytes.net mail exchanger = 10 mail.mezianeyacine.sytes.net.
mezianeyacine.sytes.net mail exchanger = 20 imap.mezianeyacine.sytes.net.
mezianeyacine.sytes.net mail exchanger = 40 pop.mezianeyacine.sytes.net.
mezianeyacine.sytes.net mail exchanger = 1 smtp.mezianeyacine.sytes.net.

Authoritative answers can be found from:

yacine@mezianeyacine:~$
```

I have verified that my server is listening on the port 25 & 587. Also i have managed the firewall to accept incoming and outgoing connection for port 25

I have found a potential solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/763294/ubuntu-postfix-not-receiving-emails-from-outside):
the issue may that the `mail.mezianeyacine.sytes.net` don't have any address records:

```
yacine@mezianeyacine:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ host mezianeyacine.sytes.net
mezianeyacine.sytes.net has address 82.66.16.108
mezianeyacine.sytes.net mail is handled by 20 imap.mezianeyacine.sytes.net.
mezianeyacine.sytes.net mail is handled by 40 pop.mezianeyacine.sytes.net.
mezianeyacine.sytes.net mail is handled by 1 smtp.mezianeyacine.sytes.net.
mezianeyacine.sytes.net mail is handled by 10 mail.mezianeyacine.sytes.net.

yacine@mezianeyacine:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ host mail.mezianeyacine.sytes.net.
Host mail.mezianeyacine.sytes.net. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

yacine@mezianeyacine:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ host smtp.mezianeyacine.sytes.net.
Host smtp.mezianeyacine.sytes.net. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
yacine@mezianeyacine:/etc/apache2/sites-available$
```

Could you help me to solve this please ? I'm not sure to what I can do to solve.

Comment: It seems you don't understand what `MX` records are for.

Comment: May be you can explain to help to solve the issue ?

Comment: An MX record says that a mail responder is listening on a specific named server. What you seem to be missing is the A record which says where that specific mail server lives. Add A records in DNS that map `smtp.mezianeyacine.sytes.net`  and `mail.mezianeyacine.sytes.net` to your server's IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to start by learning [what a DNS MX record is](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-mx-record/), which helps to understand how to use them. Your current configuration suggests you would need `MX` records for IMAP, POP, SMTP and "MAIL", but that's not how it works!

As it seems you are only having one server at `mezianeyacine.sytes.net` handling the mail and it has SMTP banner configured for the same host name, it might be easiest to forget all the subdomains. Having multiple hostnames pointing to a single server does not increase redundancy at all.

You could simply replace all your `MX` records with a single record:

```
mezianeyacine.sytes.net. IN MX 1 mezianeyacine.sytes.net.
```